# Parse error INDEX.PHP for sub-directory

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, index, .htaccess

I have created new web site for language code with sub-directory and copying two files index.php and .htacess from the root to the individual sub-directory.Then edit index.php file as:

```
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

$compilerConfig = ‘../includes/config.php’;
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}

$mageFilename = ‘../app/Mage.php’;
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';

    /* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
$mageRunCode = 'de';
$mageRunType = 'website';
```

After I edit getting a following issue;

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home/kaansilv/public_html/de/index.php on line 42
```

Also I edited .htaccess file on new sub-directory file as;

```
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase/de/
```

My site structure;

```
www.mydomain.com/en base directory  * it's fine 
www.mydomain.com/de sub-directory *new web site which I created for sub-directory
```

Also I never forget to edit store base url each store view in Magento admin.

Now I would like ask ;

Am I need make symlink for sub-directory.Because I don't know how to path edit on SSH.

Another issue ;

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/kaansilv/public_html/de/app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php55/pear') in /home/kaansilv/public_html/de/index.php on line 64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you directly copy/pasted your source, I'm going to assume that line 43 is likely `$mageFilename = ‘../app/Mage.php’;`. The string is wrapped in smart quotes, not single quotes which PHP doesn't interpret as a string. Either copy and replace the line with:

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
```

... or manually delete the quote at the start and end and make them proper single or double quotes.

Comment: As you mentioned string issue,I have changed to single quotes and issue is fixed.But now I get another issue.Please check my first post last line;

Comment: @KaanBurak it might be worth opening that as a seperate question - the answer did resolve the specific issue to do with the question. The include path would seem to be implying Magento 2 but your tags suggest 1.9 is that definately the version?

Comment: @johncuthbert I using 1.9.2.3 version